# NSURLSession background upload cancelled immediately in iOS7

Tags: background, upload, nsurlsession

I'm attempting to upload of a file using NSURLSession's support for background uploads.

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileUrl];
```

Everything works great in iOS8 but when I run the same code in iOS7, the task gets immediately cancelled with the error message:

```
"Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo=0x17df82a0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://my.url.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://my.url.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}"
```

As far as I can tell, this should be supported in iOS7 but I haven't found anything to explain why this would be happening or how to fix it.

Comment: found a solution by now? got the same issue, without uploading, just a get request, in swift 2.0, ios 8 and ios 9.

Comment: @RageCompex i'm getting the exact same thing in Swift 2 and iOS 8...did you manage to come up with a solution?

Comment: @cph2117 I am trying to remember when and where I got it and how I fixed it. My search history shows this github page: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/157 I think I had done the same, keep the manager as a global variable.

Comment: @RageCompex thanks for helping.  I actually already have a custom class that has the network manager as a retained instance, so it must be something else!

Comment: but is your custom class retained :)? Then I have no solution for you, sorry and happy debugging! We all love it so much...

Comment: Faced similar issue and I have realised that `from*:` in `NSURLSession#uploadTaskWithRequest:from*:` cannot be `nil` - thanks to Andy Ibanez who described it here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38512824/2004186